# PBKDF2 when dkLen and hLen have the same size

Tags: sha-256, pbkdf-2

I was reading [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2) and something is not clear to me. When I use PBKDF2 with SHA-256 and I want a derived key with length 32 bytes (the same length as my hash function output), your derived key only exists out 1 block (`l = 1`) of size `hLen = 32` bytes.

This seems trivially, but i want to be very sure! Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output length of the `F` step of PBKDF, i.e. the `T_i` each are of the size of your hash function's (or actually: your PRF's) output.

So yes, when the desired output size is as large (or smaller) as the hash function output, we have `l = 1` and thus only one call to `F(P, S, c, 1)`.

I suppose this is also the most common way to use PBKDF-2, the extension to longer generated key sizes is only included to make the scheme more generally usable.

Comment: The extension to longer key sizes is useful when the output is going to be an actual encryption key or other non-password storage use.  Storing an output longer than native hash size is actively counterproductive (BAD) when the output is a password hash (since the attacker only needs to attack the first block, and you wasted time calculating more than one, thus giving the attacker a [further] speed advantage over you).